# Rails ActiveRecord model scope with joins on has_many associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model, active-record-query

I’m currently setting up a scope in my Rails model to be used by ActiveAdmin. The scope I want to build should find every `Job` that has a `survey_date` in the past, with a `Job.survey` present, and no `Job.quotes` present.

Here is an abbreviated version of my `Job` model:

```
has_many :quotes
has_many :surveys

scope :awaiting_quote, lambda { joins(:surveys, :quotes).where('survey_date < :current_time AND surveys.id IS NOT NULL AND quotes.id IS NULL', { current_time: Time.current }) }
```

How should I change my scope so that it correctly finds the revelant `Job` records?

Comment: Please note `joins` will create an INNER JOIN which means that `quotes.id IS NULL` has no impact and these jobs will never show up try `includes(:surveys,:quotes).where('survey_date < :current_time AND surveys.id IS NOT NULL AND quotes.id IS NULL', { current_time: Time.current })` this will create 2 LEFT OUTER JOIN s and may function better for you. Here is a great [article](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html) on association loading and how the methods work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails 5 introduced [`left_outer_joins`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#left-outer-joins) method that can be used

```
scope :awaiting_quote, -> { joins(:surveys).left_outer_joins(:quotes).where('yada yada') }
```

Answer (score 4):

**Update for Rails 5**

As [mad_raz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1769515/mad-raz) mentions, in Rails 5.0+, you can use [`left_outer_joins`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#left-outer-joins):

```
scope :awaiting_quote, -> { joins(:surveys).
  left_outer_joins(:quotes).
  where('survey_date < :current_time', { current_time: Time.current }).
  where('quotes.id IS NULL')
}
```

However, you must still provide a `where('quotes.id IS NULL')` check to only return those records that have not yet received a quote. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16598900/1951290 for a great visual representation of outer joins.

It still probably makes the most sense to split these into two separate scopes.

---

**Rails 4**

You can create left outer joins using `joins`, you just have to be a bit more explicit.

```
scope :awaiting_quote, -> { joins(:surveys).
  joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN quotes ON quotes.job_id = jobs.id').
  where('survey_date < :current_time', { current_time: Time.current }).
  where('quotes.id IS NULL')
}
```

You don't need `surveys.id IS NOT NULL` since a successful inner join will not include nil ids.

It probably makes more sense to split these into two separate scopes, `:has_survey` and `:without_quote`, which can then be combined into a method.

```
def self.awaiting_quote
  Job.has_survey.without_quote
end
```